# Computing maximum of a ratio defined on the grid graph

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, combinatorial-proofs, planar-graphs

Consider an $n \times n$ grid graph $G$. Define the following quantity

\begin{equation}
m(G) = \text{max}\bigg\{\frac{|E|_{H'}}{|V|_{H'}},~ H' \subseteq G, ~~|V|_{H'} > 0 \bigg\},
\end{equation}

where $|V|_{H'}$ and $|E|_{H'}$ are the number of vertices and edges of the graph $H'$ respectively. I am trying to compute this for the grid graph.

---

Here's my approach. If I take the entire grid, then I have $n^2$ vertices and $2n^2 -2n$ edges. So, $m(G)$ is at least $2 - \frac{2}{n}$. Is this more or less tight or can we do something better?

Comment: This is known as the densest subgraph problem. This is equivalent to maximizing the average degree of the graph (since the average degree of a graph is $\frac{2m}{n}$). The full grid will be optimal because you want to maximize the number of degree $4$ vertices (in the interior of the subgraph) compared to the degree $2$ and $3$ vertices (on the border of the subgraph).
The shape that maximize this ratio is clearly the full grid.